# Recieved "can't load android system your data may be corrupt" a couple of times, then booted. Should I wory?

Tags: boot-loop

When hanging up a phone call, the phone turned off and rebooted. I have received the "can't load android system your data may be corrupt" two or three times in a row. I set it aside and found it turned on later. This is a google pixel 4a with android 12 build SQ1A.211205.008. I am a newb, so I am giving the details I think are required and if something is missing please add in the comments and I will edit.

Should I worry? Can I somehow find the cause? can it be a virus? should I do anything?

In general, what do you do if you receive this message and it goes away?